# Perform job only if are right conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm using active job with sidekiq adapter and I want perform job only if some condition are met, eg. I append to queue but I don't want perform any item from queue unles the specific redis flag is set. How can I accomplish that? If in before trigger I will check if flag was set and throw exception it will working, I suppose, but it doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: job, condition, items, redis flag, before trigger ... ? Can you describe your problem more thoroughly or – better yet – show some code? It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish or what's missing.

Comment: What do you expect when the flag is not set? Should the job stay in the queue? Should it immediately start once the flag is set? Or do you want the jobs to be removed from the queue? Should all jobs be handled that way or just specific one?

Comment: If flag was not set I want to not pop item from queue. So only thing I want to accomplish is preventing from poping until condition will true

Answer (score 0):

```
class SendNotificationsJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  queue_as :default

  def perform(order)
    order_status = $redis_server.get("#{order.id}:status")
    unless 'done' == order_status
      SendNotificationsJob.set(wait: 10.minutes).perform_later(order)
      return # end this job. new job will check in 10min later
    end
    # fill here
  end
end
```

This will work without [retrying issues](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#automatic-job-retry). however, my recommendation is to use an event machine like [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm). invoke the job when necessary. otherwise, you are wasting resources.